# how to get XML from a website and put it on my webserver by code or script

Tags: java, xml, http

If there is an website who provides an XML for example: https://www.example.com/getbasket

Because from my system which is built in IBM notes/lotus notes, with an Agent i cannot get the xml because i get a com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: Certificate chaining error

So what i want to do, is get the xml file and put it on my webserver and then retrieve it from my webserver via an php or javascript way, is this possible?
Or are there maybe any other suggestions

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is example in php

```
<?php

file_put_contents("server.xml", fopen("https://www.example.com/getbasket.xml", 'r'));

?>
```

Here is command line

```
wget "https://www.example.com/getbasket"
```

Comment: this works locally but online it gives me an error: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: is it shared hosting? Or you have your own server?

Comment: i have bought my hosting at a hosting provider, they host it